# How to find all views with invalid column names

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to refresh all my views using code I found on the web:

```
DECLARE @ViewName VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE cViews CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT name from sys.views
OPEN cViews
FETCH NEXT FROM cViews INTO @ViewName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS != -1
BEGIN
    EXEC SP_REFRESHVIEW @ViewName
    PRINT 'View ''' + @ViewName + ''' has been refreshed.'
    FETCH NEXT FROM cViews INTO @ViewName
END
CLOSE cViews
DEALLOCATE cViews
```

I am getting the error `Error Message: Invalid column name 'CloseDate'.`, but it's not telling me which view has the error. How would I find the name of all views with an invalid column name with the name of the invalid column? Thank you.

Comment: How about adding a PRINT statement before SP_REFRESHVIEW? This will give you the view name and of course if SP_REFRESHVIEW errors out it will give you the error details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try importing the database into an SSDT database project and building the project. It should report this type of thing.

Alternatively you could try

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.views
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (
                                        CONCAT(QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID)), '.', QUOTENAME(NAME)), 
                                        'OBJECT')
```

And then peruse the error output

[image]

Comment: When I run that query, I get a similar popup message about the invalid column name, but then it retrieves the records like normal. I don't see where I would find that error output.

Comment: Run it in SSMS and look at the messages tab to see what errors are listed. There is no popup window.

Comment: And you can use `sys.procedures` to view similar output for SPs.

Answer (score 1):

I use sql_modules for this sorta thing, sys.sql_modules. It should return results for stored procedures and views and functions; the definition field allows for wild cards.

SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition like '%CloseDate%'

And as far as a mechanism to check all views, you can do this using SQL or SSIS. For SSIS, create a package that dumps the name of all your views into a worktable or temp table. Create a ForEachLoop and do something like a "SELECT TOP 1" from each view. If it errors, dump the name of the view to a log table. For SQL, almost the same thing except use a TRY CATCH block and in your CATCH dump the name of the view to a log table.